# Is it possible to design an aircraft as big as A380 with 2 engines?

Tags: aircraft-design, engine, airbus-a380

As it is generally seen, 2 engines are more efficient than 4 engines. So, can we have so powerful engines to design an aircraft as big as A380 with 2 engines?

Comment: Difficult to understand the logic behind closing this answer and providing a link to another closed question. Furthermore the other question doesn't really provide the answer. VTR

Comment: @mins The reasons are the same, just a little more extreme with an A380 than a 747. Dupe closing seems reasonable to me. If anything, the other one could be re-opened. It should also be noted that OP was one of the dupe close votes.